# How to find callback function name from hcaptcha?

Tags: web-scraping, callback, captcha, 2captcha, hcaptcha

I'm trying to bypass hcaptcha without submit button.

So I need to know the callback name function but I can't find it in the source code of the page.

Any idea how to submit my request after received my token thx to a captcha resolver ?

Looks like it's possible for recaptcha : https://gist.github.com/2captcha/2ee70fa1130e756e1693a5d4be4d8c70

But can't find the same solution for hcaptcha.

Thx for the help.

Comment: You might get help for this if you post the link.

Comment: Ahah true. It's this website : https://www.pagesjaunes.fr/.   When you go with a VPN on it, the hcaptcha will appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks pretty straightforward actually:

```
$('form').submit()
```

Comment: Thx it was the good way to validate the hcaptcha. Unfortunatly it looks likes the hcaptacha can't be bypass even if I resolve the captha myself by hand. Is it possible the website can't be accessible with a VPN ?

Comment: Sometimes if they really don't trust you they'll send more than one...

Answer (score 0):

It's what I did to validate the hcaptcha. But unfortunatly the captcha ask me again to fill it even if I send him a validate token

```js
await page.$eval('textarea', (e, token) => {
    e.value = token
}, token)

await page.waitForTimeout(1000 + randomTime()*3)

await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('form').submit())
```